# How can I upload new lambda code from s3 via nodejs?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, lambda

I would like to upload new code to lambda via my nodejs script.

How can I do it? Which function should I use it?

My code is in zip on my s3 https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/mybuckettest/lambda-code.zip

[lambda gui img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXnZt.png)

Comment: can you provide more information?  What have you tried?  What is not working?  Check out the [posting guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Node.js, you can interact with the AWS Lambda service via the [AWS.Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Lambda.html) SDK.

Specifically, to deploy code to a Lambda function, you can use:

- [createFunction](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Lambda.html#createFunction-property)
- [updateFunctionCode](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Lambda.html#updateFunctionCode-property)